# Prove no DFA with four states can accept L={111}

Tags: automata, finite-automata, nondeterminism

Assume we have a language L={111}. Prove no DFA with four states can accept L.

Can’t a DFA with 4 states accept L?

Comment: No, no DFA with 4 states can accept $L=\{111\}$.

Comment: Hint: Consider how to _not_ accept words which are not in $L$.

Comment: How about q0 -> q1 -> q2 -> q3 and each transition occurs on the symbol 1? @Steven

Comment: That DFA has 5 states, not $4$. (There is one implicit state to handle all the transitions you have not specified. The transition function of a DFA must be a total function.)

Comment: Does a DFA need a transition for every symbol in the alphabet?

Comment: Depends on how you define it, but in the usual (vanilla) definition requires that.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on your favorite definition for DFAs. If your definition allows the transition function to be undefined on some state-symbol pairs $(q, a)$ then your DFA in your [comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/136193/prove-no-dfa-with-four-states-can-accept-l-111#comment286836_136193) does the trick. Otherwise, you would need a fifth state (a sink) that is not accepting and catches all missing transitions.

To show that there is no DFA with less than five states accepting $L = \{111\}$, we can check the [Myhill-Nerode equivalence classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) of $L$ which are

- $[\varepsilon]_L = \{\varepsilon\}$,
- $[1]_L = \{1\}$,
- $[11]_L = \{11\}$,
- $[111]_L = \{111\}$,
- $[0]_L = \{w \in \{0, 1\}^\ast \mid w \notin \{\varepsilon, 1, 11, 111\}\}$.

(To show that these are indeed the five classes is left as exercise.)

The equivalence classes have a 1:1 correspondence to the unique minimal DFA of the latter definition (with transitions for all state-symbol pairs).

Comment: Notice that for the Myhill-Nerode theorem to work, the definition of DFA must require that transition function is a total function. Otherwise, as OP has shown, the theorem is not true since the number of states of a DFA that recognizes a language can be smaller than the number of equivalence classes.

Comment: Using this theorem is nice, but overkill ...